# SSIS convert object variables to string in expression builder

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I have a few queries in my SSIS package where I need to loop through a bunch of table names pulled from a query.  In he foreach container it puts the table names into a variable, and this works fine.

In the foreach container I then have an 'Execute SQL Task' which executes a variable which contains the SQL code to extract all the column names into a single string:

```
"SELECT CAST((SELECT 
'[' + STRING_AGG(CAST(c.[COLUMN_NAME] AS nvarchar(MAX)) , '], [') + ']' AS ColumnName
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t 
LEFT JOIN  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c  ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA 
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'hist' AND t.TABLE_NAME = '"
+
@[User::TableName] 
+
"' GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME)
 AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS ColumnNames"
```

This string I would like to use in an expression in another variable where the column names are needed in a query. But I cannot seem to store them in a variable which is a string, as it is an object. Whenever I try to store it in a variable which is a string, then it fails saying that that it cannot store an object in a string variable.

I have tried casting it as a nvarchar(MAX) as has been suggested and accepted as a solution in this post:
[SSIS convert object variable to string in expression builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877677/ssis-convert-object-variable-to-string-in-expression-builder)

I have also tried the Script Task option, but as I am not experienced in this, I cannot seem to make this work.

Right now the Execute SQL Task returns a ResultSet as a Single Row, and in the Parameter Mapping I've selected the string variable as input, and in the Result Set I have it to return the object into an object variable for the purpose. This does not fail, but when I try to execute the next query where the column names are needed, it fails because the variable is empty, meaning that nothing is put into the string variable where I need the column names.

Is there any way I can put the string value into the string variable so I can use it for other expressions?

Comment: Your example is a bit difficult to follow. You should have only one object variable - the one with the table names. In your for-each part you execute a query, which should return the columns in a string - so the result of this SQL task should be astring, not an object...

Comment: It seems that you understand it the way I do. And I'm trying to do as you say, but if i put it into a variable which is a string, it is giving me an error saying that I cannot put in an object into a string. So my difficulty is how to insert the result of my query into a string variable.

Comment: If you have more than 1 row of data you can not convert that to a string it would be an object because it has more than 1 row.  When debugging SSIS I have script task (C#) that I pass my variables to and prints them as message box.  so I can see what is in the variable each loop.  Then you run that code in SQL to see what happens what is returned.  If you can show your script task it would help

Comment: I always only have ONE value of data, I never get more from the query I'm running.